# Hibernate: Can't use CascadeType.PERSIST

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have in my DB Categories and Items which are related in many to many.
My goal is that when I add Items to the items list in the category, these items will automatically be added to the DB.
I thought that Annotating the list of items in the category by CascadeType.PERSIST will do the work, but it doesn't. Putting all the CascaseTypes enum values also doesn't work.
Each time I get the following exception when committing the transaction:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: il.co.site_building.webutils.shop.Item
```

**Only when I annotate this with CascadeType.ALL, the items are saved properly.**

The code for the Category:

```
public Category(Integer uid,
                  String name,
                  String displayName,
                  Category parent,
                  List<Category> subCategories,
                  List<Item> items){
    m_uid             = uid;
    m_name            = name;
    m_displayName     = displayName;
    m_parent          = parent;
    m_subCategories   = subCategories;
    m_itemsInCategory = items != null ? items : new LinkedList<>();
  }

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) //Doesn't work. Only CascadeType.ALL will work.
  @JoinTable(name = "items_categories",
             joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="category") },
             inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "item")})
  public List<Item> getItemsInCategory(){return m_itemsInCategory;}
```

The code for the Item:

```
public Item(Integer uid,
              String name,
              String displayName,
              String description,
              BigDecimal price,
              Integer orderIndex,
              String serialNo,
              AttributeType attributeType,
              List<ItemAttribute> itemAttributes,
              List<Category> categories){
    m_uid            = uid;
    m_name           = name;
    m_displayName    = displayName;
    m_description    = description;
    m_price          = price.setScale(PRICE_SCALE);
    m_orderIndex     = orderIndex;
    m_serialNo       = serialNo;
    m_attributeType  = attributeType;
    m_itemAttributes = itemAttributes != null ? itemAttributes : new LinkedList<>();
    m_categories     = categories != null? categories : new LinkedList<>();
  }

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "itemsInCategory")
  public List<Category> getCategories(){return m_categories;}
```

The code for inserting items (Assuming the category already exists):

```
public static final String SHIRT_NAME = "shirt";
public static final String SHIRT_DISPLAY_NAME = "shirt display";
public static final String SHIRT_DESCRIPTION = "shirt description";
public static final BigDecimal SHIRT_PRICE = new BigDecimal("2.01");
public static final Integer SHIRT_ORDER_INDEX = 1;
public static final String SHIRT_SERIAL_NUMBER = "shirt_sn";

public static final Item SHIRT = new Item(null,
                                          SHIRT_NAME,
                                          SHIRT_DISPLAY_NAME,
                                          SHIRT_DESCRIPTION,
                                          SHIRT_PRICE,
                                          SHIRT_ORDER_INDEX,
                                          SHIRT_SERIAL_NUMBER,
                                          AttributeTypeTest.ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_SIZE,
                                          null, null);
session.beginTransaction();
Query query.setParameter("uid", CategoryTest.CATEGORY_SHIRTS.getUid()); //This category was persisted properly somewhere else
Category category = (Category)query.uniqueResult();
List<Item> itemsInCategory = category.getItemsInCategory();
SHIRT.getCategories().add(category); itemsInCategory.add(SHIRT);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: as I found out the problem related to using jpa annotations with native hybernate api. If you use JPA syntax the PERSIT would work as you have expected.

Answer (score 1):

So it is Hibernate problem when using its native API with JPA annotated classes.

Hibernate does not persist child objects when the relationship is annotated with `CascadeType.PERSIST` but only for `CascadeType.ALL` annotated relationships.

However, if you use Hibernate via JPA API (so EntityManger instead of Session, rest of the code is almost identical),
then both `CascadeType.PERSIST` and `CascadeType.ALL` triggers persistence of the child elements. Which is apparently part of JPA specification (thanks to Chris for pointing it out) even if it is omitted in the javadocs.
I always mistakenly believed that only explicit persist() requests are cascaded.

If it is not too late for your project, you may consider using JPA standard instead of hibernate API. Transition is almost seamless for the new code (persist instead of save, remove instead of delete ....)

Comment: JPA section 3.2.4 requires that a provider persist unmanaged instances referenced from managed entities when checking for changes during flush or commit - if the relation was marked with cascade persist.   Same as if you called persist directly on the managed instance.

Comment: @Chris I had to check it as I always knew otherwise and you are of course right. So why his code is not working then.